# WMIC query to derive absolute share paths on LAN in Windows 10

Tags: batch-file, cmd, wmic

I'm trying to derive an absolute or full local path from a network path of a folder on a PC drive on LAN using WMIC or similar network tool run from a batch. A few threads devoted to similar tasks on this site when tested don't offer working solution in Win 10.

For example, when running a suggested in one answer query in Win 10 Cmd, I got:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>wmic share where "name='\\Laptop\Data'" get path
Node - OFFICE
ERROR:
Description = Invalid query

C:\WINDOWS\system32>wmic share where "name='Data'" get path
No Instance(s) Available.
```

I need this result: *K:\Data* , where K:\ is a hard drive of the remote PC on LAN, and Data is shared folder on that drive.

Can someone suggest a working query & batch for that task? WMIC documentation is way too extensive to derive a working query by trial-and-error without significant experience in using the tool.

Comment: if `\\laptop\data` is *not* an absolute path, please define what you mean by `absolute`.

Comment: Absolute path in this case would be K:\Data , where K:\ is the drive letter of the hard drive volume, mounted on that remote PC.

Comment: You should edit that into the question (since [absolute path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths) is commonly used with a different meaning).

Comment: So you want the path to the share, as though you are asking the remote machine?

Comment: Yes, I need a full path to the share on LAN. The term "absolute path" is used in several threads for similar tasks, but I can edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggested in the thread techniques worked with certain additional actions.

When using WMIC, I had to [add](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26266529/WMI-Error-The-RPC-server-is-unavailable.html) local admin account to *WMI Control Security* property. As well, by running *GPEDIT.msc* [enabled](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6fbf3994-1241-4657-8a4b-f504227c59fa/group-policy-error-the-rpc-server-is-unavailable?forum=winserverGP) "*Allow inbound remote administration exceptions*" to Firewall rules, despite Firewall was disabled. The proper query is below, processing it's output required a batch file similar in approach to PsExec batch:

```
wmic /user:[username] /password:[password] /node:"PC-ID" share get

@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2 skip=1 delims=:" %%u in ('wmic /user:[username] /password:[password] /node:"Laptop" share get') do @(
    set "var1=%%u" & set "var2=%%v"
    set "var1.1=!var1:~89,-1!" & set "var2=!var2:~0,33!" & set "var1.2=!var1:~97!" & set "var1.3=!var1.1:~0,4!"
    if not "!var1.3!"=="IPC$" if not "!var1.1!"=="" echo \\Laptop\!var1.1! = !var1.2!:!var2!) 
exit /b

::Output
\\Laptop\ADMIN$   = C:\WINDOWS
\\Laptop\C$       = C:\
\\Laptop\D$       = D:\
\\Laptop\Data     = K:\
\\Laptop\K$       = K:\
\\Laptop\Docs     = K:\Other\Docs
\\Laptop\print$   = C:\windows\system32\spool\drivers
```

When using PsExec instead of WMIC, I had to [install](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pxexec) it first, then [add](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_security/psexec-get-console-access-windows-10-problem/ad96c6db-95d7-46ab-98c8-e03efa35df5e?auth=1) an extra key *LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy* in Registry, then modify the command posted earlier:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%u in ('psexec64 -u [username] -p [password] \\Laptop cmd /c net share 2^>nul') do @(
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%x in ("%%u %%v") do @(
        if not "%%y"=="" echo \\Laptop\%%u = %%v ) )
exit /b

::Output
\\Laptop\C$ = C:\
\\Laptop\D$ = D:\
\\Laptop\print$ = C:\windows\system32\spool\drivers
\\Laptop\K$ = K:\
\\Laptop\ADMIN$ = C:\WINDOWS
\\Laptop\Data = K:\
\\Laptop\Docs = K:\Other\Docs
```

Answer (score 1):

```
wmic share where name='C$' get path
```

Works here (as only one test doesn't need double quotes). So does

```
wmic share where "name='C$'" get path
```

What you posted says you don't have a share called `data`.

```
wmic share get /format:list
```

Shows you what you have.

```
C:\Users\User>wmic share get
AccessMask  AllowMaximum  Caption        Description    InstallDate  MaximumAllowed  Name    Path        Status  Type
            TRUE          Remote Admin   Remote Admin                                ADMIN$  C:\Windows  OK      2147483648
            TRUE          Default share  Default share                               C$      C:\         OK      2147483648
            TRUE          Default share  Default share                               D$      D:\         OK      2147483648
            TRUE          fred                                                       fred    C:\Intel    OK      0
            TRUE          Default share  Default share                               G$      G:\         OK      2147483648
            TRUE          Remote IPC     Remote IPC                                  IPC$                OK      2147483651
            TRUE          TestC                                                      TestC   C:\         OK      0
```

As usual `wmic /?`, `wmic share /?`, `wmic share call /?`, `wmic share get /?`, `wmic /format /?`.

For remote computers you have to connect to that computer (see `wmic /node /?`).

```
wmic /node:127.0.0.1 share get
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't work here for network paths, only for local paths. Pls note, I already have a known network path.

Comment: That's your query. So it does work. SHARES are what a machines shares with others.

Comment: Your solution lists only local shares of the PC it runs on, but not shares of other PCs on LAN. At least for me. :)

Comment: What's the right way to add LAN PC name? `C:\WINDOWS\system32>wmic /node:Laptop share get
Invalid Global Switch.`

Comment: If your computer's name is `Laptop` it should work. Type `net view` to see turned on computers.

Comment: `C:\WINDOWS\system32>NET VIEW
System error 6118 has occurred.
The list of servers for this workgroup is not currently available` Note that both PCs are on the same workgroup, and the Data share is in fact mounted on both.

Comment: You probably have Server and Workstation services disabled. Use an IP address in this case (or turn on File and Print sharing, join the workgroup, enable services).

Comment: Both Ps aren't servers, but workstations. File and Printer Sharing is turned On on both, Workstation service is running on both Win10 Pro.

Comment: Upon reboot with all A/V FW off I get: `C:\WINDOWS\system32>net view
Server Name            Remark

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\OFFICE
The command completed successfully.` This is despite the Data share is mounted on both PCs.

Comment: In Windows terminology they are both servers and workstations. Servers wait for something to connect. Workstations (in windows networking - more generally clients) initiate the connection. Both computers MUST have windows networking configured. If you can connect by IP and not by name then you need to turn on Computer Browser. **Computer Browser, Workstation, and Server** are the names used in the services applet user interface.

Comment: `Laptop` is not part of your network, though a computer called `office` is. So `wmic /node:office share get`

Comment: Office is local PC. I need full paths on Laptop, and its on the same workgroup. `C:\WINDOWS\system32>wmic /node:192.168.6.274 share get
Node - 192.168.6.274
ERROR:
Description = Access is denied.` All above services are up on both PCs, FW and AV are down.

Comment: Are you running WMIC as administrator?. There is also the `/user:domain\username` and `/password:password` - enclose in quotes if they contain spaces.

Comment: Yes, as admin. `C:\WINDOWS\system32>wmic /user:sam /password:bul /node:192.168.6.274 share get
Node - 192.168.6.274
ERROR:
Description = The RPC server is unavailable.` I followed [this](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26266529/WMI-Error-The-RPC-server-is-unavailable.html), still the same error.

Comment: Managed to get share list from the laptop after enabling FW policy & adding permissions, but only with /node:IP_address. Still doesn't work with /node:PC_name. Why?

Comment: Double quotes for <machine ID> may be required.

Answer (score 1):

The following lists the drive letters mapped on the **local** machine to the (currently connected) remote shares.

```
C:\etc>for /f "tokens=1-3" %x in ('net use') do @if /i "%x" equ "ok" echo %z = %y

\\laptop\x$ = P:
\\laptop\data = Q:
```

---

Following the OP edit (**highlight** mine):

[+ **EDIT** for correct `net share` usage]

> I need this result: K:\Data , where K:\ is a hard drive **of the remote PC** on LAN, and Data is shared folder on that drive.

If you need the `K:` drive letter assigned on the **remote** machine to the drive containing the shared directory, then you could run `net share` remotely using [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg697102.aspx) or similar (provided you have an account with enough rights on the remote machine).

For example, assuming `\\laptop` is another machine on the LAN, the following will list the share names and (remote) directories on `\\laptop`.

```
C:\etc>for /f "tokens=1,2" %u in ('psexec \\laptop cmd /c net share 2^>nul') do @(
         for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %x in ("%u %v") do @(
           if not "%y"=="" echo "\\laptop\%u" = "%v" ) )

"\\laptop\C$" = "C:\"
"\\laptop\ADMIN$" = "C:\Windows"
"\\laptop\DATA" = "K:\Data"
```

Comment: I didn't map any drive letters on the local machine to network shares, since they are mounted dynamically and accessible in Win Explorer without drive letters. I need namely remote full paths, which they already have.

Comment: Besides, I'm gettings: `C:\WINDOWS\system32>net use
New connections will be remembered.

There are no entries in the list.` This is despite the network share is already mounted on the local PC. I use Admin Cmd Prompt.

Comment: @sambul35 Per the 2nd part of the answer, for the *remote* paths to the shares you'll need to run `net use` on the *remote* machine. It might help if you elaborated on what the ultimate goal is, since drive-letter-based paths on a remote machine are not too useful in most common scenarios.

Comment: Surprisingly, I got exact same output on the 2nd PC, despite the share is mounted on both PCs. Win 10 is up-to-date. The  goal is to develop a tool that would create a list of absolute paths on LAN given the list of network paths.

Comment: Actually, you need to run `net share`, not `net use` on the *remote* machine. I made the necessary correction in the answer.